# MTaaS causing resource leak

Tags: java, android, testing, google-play-console, resource-leak

After uploading a binary to Google Play, my app was shut down upon launch by Android on one of the test devices according to the [Pre-Launch Report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en).

The issue seems to be a resource leak, cause by:

```
com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform
```

I managed to find out that MTaaS most likely stands for *Mobile Testing as a Service*.

Am I correct that the testing framework leaks resources causing the test to be aborted?

How can I stop MTaaS from leaking?

Full device log from Galaxy S9 in [Strict Mode](https://blog.mindorks.com/use-strictmode-to-find-things-you-did-by-accident-in-android-development-4cf0e7c8d997):

Note: This is from an NDK based app, with little Java code, and no dependency on FireBase.

```
E/StrictMode(14355): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
E/StrictMode(14355): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
E/StrictMode(14355):        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:223)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:192)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:181)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:425)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.common.base.IOUtils.makeParcelAsync(IOUtils.java:1)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.ScreenState.writeScreenElementsToParcel(ScreenState.java:141)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.ScreenState.writeToParcel(ScreenState.java:60)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.platform.ParcelableScreenState.writeToParcel(ParcelableScreenState.java:6)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1746)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1652)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:793)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:833)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Message.writeToParcel(Message.java:594)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.IMessenger$Stub$Proxy.send(IMessenger.java:84)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Messenger.send(Messenger.java:57)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.sendMessage(RemotePlatform.java:39)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.sendActionResultsMessage(RemotePlatform.java:64)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.handlePerformActionMessage(RemotePlatform.java:24)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.access$300(RemotePlatform.java:88)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform$ControllerMessageHandler.handleMessage(RemotePlatform.java:8)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/StrictMode(14355):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
W/System.err(14355): StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be a bug in the Google Play pre-launch report crawler. I can inform the appropriate team, but in general if this happens you can let them know via Play console support. You can contact them via the help menu in the Google Play console. This is behind the question mark "?" icon.

Answer (score 0):

I am a part of MTaaS and investigating this issue. But I dont have any details specific to this issue/crawl (e.g., logcat or package name).

Does this stacktrace appear as the cause of failure on PLR or it is extracted from the logcat to help us debug? If it is the later, could you share the stacktrace that appear on PLR.

Comment: The snippet is from the logcat that I downloaded from the Prelaunch Report for com.steenriver.armor. Full logcat is here: https://stolk.org/tmp/logcat.txt

Comment: Thanks for noticing the issue and reporting it. It has been fixed and will be released hopefully next week.